# Blog module for Drupal 6

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, module, blogs

I have cerated a custom Template for Drupal 6 and now I would like to add a Blog but I'm not sure about the module to use.

Do you have any suggetsion ? I will need to change my template to work on blog ?

Thanks for any suggestion!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Drupal 6 comes with a Blog module in core.  Navigate to `admin/build/modules` to enable it.  It will work out of the box.  If you need to change the template for a blog post you can do that as well.

To change the template for the blog listing **page**: create a new instance of page.tpl.php and name it page-blog.tpl.php and customize to your liking.

To change the blog **node** template: create a new instance of node.tpl.php and name it node-blog.tpl.php and customize to your liking.

For more on creating templates, see [Drupal 6 Template Suggestions](http://drupal.org/node/1089642)

Comment: Thanks Laxman! At the moment I'm using 2 fles as template: one for front page and the other for custom page. Will be possible to create a new one template page just for the blog ?

Comment: @Uncoke see my edited answer above

Comment: Thanks!  I'll test it tomorrow but I think this is what I was loking for.  Thanks a lot!